# Import screenshot from gallery photos and set as background in Xcode 6.3 Swift

Tags: ios, iphone, swift

I've taken a screenshot (of the lock screen) on my iPhone 6 and got it into the iPhone 6 simulator. I pick the image by presenting an imagePicker controller and then set it in the didFinishPcikingMediaWithInfo as follows:

```
func imagePickerController(picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [NSObject : AnyObject]) {
    self.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil);

    let refImage = info[UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage] as! UIImage

    self.view.backgroundColor = UIColor(patternImage: refImage)
}
```

This results in a display like this:
[image: iPhone6 Simulator size wrong]

I also tried changing the final line to be:

```
let frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, image.size.width, image.size.height)
let backgroundView = UIImageView(frame: frame)
backgroundView.image = image
backgroundView.contentMode = .ScaleAspectFill
self.view.addSubview(backgroundView)
```

and also tried
    backgroundView.contentMode = .ScaleAspectFit

Any idea why the screenshot is doubling in size and seemingly won't fit? Im guessing a resolution issue of some kind?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change this

```
let frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, image.size.width, image.size.height)
```

to

```
let frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.size.height)
```

If this doesn't work and you are using storyboard then drag and drop a UIImageview, connect it through IBOutlet and then set your UIImage.